# Batch Update MongoDB timestamps

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a few records in my collection. And one of the keys is 'available_on'
which is a datetime/timestamp value. I want to batch update and add an
interval to all these fields.

Desired usage is like:

```
coll.update({}, {'$inc': {'available_on': 1 day}}, multi=true)
```

I am using pymongo 1.10 and from what I understand there is no way to
provide JavaScript code to `update` or `find_and_modify`. And I can only use
update modifiers.

Answer (score -3):

I don't knew the Python API, but you can find an entry with JavaScript using $where, for example in the JavaScript Shell:

```
db.collection.find({$where: 'this.field > 3'});
```

But consider that finding an entry based on JavaScript can be slow. I think no index can be used, and you end up with a table scan.

You find more of this in the official documentation: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution

I think the "normal" way is, that you find all your entries that you want to change. Change the objects in your Python Code, and save the new modified objects in your database.

Comment: I have been using the same iterative approach. That's why i asked if there was any "Batch" operation to do it :-)